# Why is the d3 element not appending when the list item is rendered?

Tags: javascript, meteor, d3.js

I have a list of items that expands for each when in focus.

```
{{#if inFocus}}    
    {{>d3Hello}} 
{{/if}}
```

Yet the span element does not append when it is in focus:

```
Template.d3Hello.onRendered(function(){
    d3.select("#plot").append("span")
        .text("Hello, world!");
    console.log(Date.now()) //This does log everytime the list item is clicked and d3 is inFocus.  But the span is not appended.   

})
```

Plot is an id within this template:

```
<template name="d3Hello">
    <svg id="plot">PLOT</svg> 
</template>
```

Why could this be?

The weirdest part is that when I run`$('#plot').html()` in the console I see this, but if I use the inspector I don't see anything, but the svg itself.

```
"PLOT<span>Hello, world!</span><span>Hello, world!</span>"
```

Comment: What exactly is `plot`?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Its a div with an id `#plot`

Comment: I'm suspicious that it has something to do with being a list item, because in another project when it is a just a template that renders on load (not on click) it works perfectly.

Comment: I just changed it to `
<template name="d3Hello">
 <svg id="plot">PLOT</svg> 
</template>
` but still it does not work.